# How do I get multiple ToC entries in the same line?

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, memoir

I need that, in the ToC, all the `\paragraph` references appear in the same line, like.

```
1 First Chapter................................................1
 1.1 First Section.............................................1
   One paragraph 1, Another § 3, One more § 4
 1.2 Second Section.......................................7
   § in sec. two 7, Another § in sec. two 11
```

And so on… I'm using the `memoir` class, which, in its manual, actually uses this for its subsections, but don't explain how to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`titletoc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) provides a means to format ToC-entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{titletoc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc
\titlecontents*{subsection}% <section>
  [1.5em]% <left>
  {\small}% <above-code>
  {}% <numbered-entry-format>; you could also use {\thecontentslabel. } to show the numbers
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\ \thecontentspage}% <filler-page-format>
  [,\ ]% <separator>
  []% <end>
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% Display up to \subsection in ToC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter} \lipsum
\section{First section} \lipsum
\subsection{One paragraph} \lipsum
\subsection{Another paragraph} \lipsum
\subsection{One more paragraph} \lipsum
\section{Second section} \lipsum
\subsection{Paragraph in section two} \lipsum
\subsection{Another paragraph in section two} \lipsum
\end{document}
```

I've left the original no-dotted-leader for the chapter formatting, since the **bold** typeface already links the title with the page number. However, it would be possible to add this as well.

I also typeset your paragraphs as `\subsection`s, since there's no need to use `\pararaph` here. Not sure whether this is what you're after, since you only mentioned ToC specifications. I've also left the `Contents` in the ToC, which can be removed, if needed.

Page 16 of the [`titletoc` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) describes the layout of the command `\titlecontents`. Remember to compile twice for the ToC entries to settle.

Comment: marlonob is using `memoir`.  Your solution will also work, but you need to add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` to get subsections into the TOC (which `memoir` doesn't do by default.)

Comment: @AlanMunn: Yikes! Thanks for picking that up.

Comment: @Werner: Hey! Just what I needed. One more thing: I have changed the format for the page numbers --just the page numbers, not the title-- to be sans serif and `\tiny` with the `memoir` `\renewcommand*{\cftparagraphpagefont}{\sffamily\tiny}`. This is much more clear because of the numbers after the section sign, which can be confusing. Any idea of how to preserve that or stablish it with `titletoc`?. I will check the documentation anyway. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the `memoir` manual long ToC for in-line subsections.

There is a package file `memsty.sty` which includes the code

```
% memsty.sty
....
\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionfont}{\itshape}
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\itshape}
  \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{
    \ifnum\c@tocdepth > 1\relax
      \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%
      \leftskip=\cftsubsectionindent
      \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
%%      \advance\rightskip 0pt plus \hsize % uncomment this for raggedright
%%      \advance\rightskip 0pt plus 2em    % uncomment this for semi-ragged
      \parfillskip=\fill
      \ifhmode ,\ \else\noindent\fi
      \ignorespaces 
      {\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
       \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces
    \fi}}

\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}%%% OK

...
```

where the macro `\setupparasubsecs` makes the `subsection` entries in the ToC be in-line rather than on a line each.

The code for the manual includes

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{memsty}
...
\setupparsubsecs
\tableofcontents
...
\end{document}
```