# Making subsubsections horizontally in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

How can make my table of contents like in the book of Allain Hatcher "Algebraic topology?"[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us a screenshot of that toc?

Comment: Probably related: [How do I get multiple ToC entries in the same line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38851/134144)

Comment: @Mensch I put a screen here ☝️

Comment: @leandriis thank you

Comment: @pluton I try to do the same but it is not working!

Comment: I have just added a second answer to the referenced question https;//tex.stackexchange/questions/38851 If this question had not been closed as a duplicate I would have added that answer here, also dealing with the lack of `subsection` numbers in the ToC..

Comment: @user975332 Can you please share a Minimal and Compilable Example?